# Data structure for fast finding of item in List

Tags: scala

I'm working on utilising a data structure that finds items in the list while avoiding traversing the linked list of items. For this I've decided to use IndexSeq (https://www.programcreek.com/scala/scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq)

I've also considered the following :

List https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/List.html but did not use List as "This includes the index-based lookup of elements, length, append and reverse."

Is IndexSeq a "good" data structure to use to avoid traversing the entire list of items ?

This is how I plan to use `IndexedSeq` :

```
class MyDataStructure() {
  var v1 = IndexedSeq[Int]()

  def append(num  :Int) = {
    v1 = v1 :+ num
  }

  def getIndexSeq = {
    v1
  }

  def getAtIndex(index : Int) = {
    v1(index)
  }
}

object MyDataStructure {
  def apply() : MyDataStructure = new MyDataStructure()
}

object TestDS extends App {
  val ds = MyDataStructure()
  ds.append(1)
  ds.append(2)

  println(ds.getIndexSeq)
  println(ds.getAtIndex(1))
}
```

which prints :

```
Vector(1, 2)
2
```

Vector extends IndexSeq (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Vector.html) so I just use Vector as "It provides random access and updates in effectively constant time, as well as very fast append and prepend. " , therefore accessing items is fast also ?

Comment: `IndexedSeq` is not a data structure is just an interface. - In any case, what do you mean by _"fast finding an item"_? If you actually mean fast access by index then yeah, anything that extends `IndexedSeq` would work, but since you also need to keep appending elements it would be good to use an `IndexedSeq` that also has a fast append, `Vector` is that data structure. My advice, use that directly instead of the _(useless)_ interface.

Comment: Just use `IndexSeq`, no need for additional stuctures. And you are not supposed to care about concrete implementation. If you do `val foo = IndexedSeq(1,2,3)`, you are using `IndexedSeq`, whatever implementation the library decides to return to you - a `Vector` or something else - is immaterial.

Comment: Any spefic reason for not using an `Array[Int]` ?

Comment: @sarveshseri not using Array as needing good performance for adding to List I believe array is slower to append than List as full traversal is required for an Array?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, when I said `Array`, I meant Java's `ArrayList` or Scala's `ArrayBuffer`, both of these have `amotrised constant` append.